# SQLite - error "sqlite3.OperationalError: near ",": syntax error"

Tags: python-2.7, datetime, sqlite

this simple issue has me stumped and while I expect its an easy fix I haven't been able to find the necessary change.

What I'm trying to accomplish is build a simple DB table that contains yesterdays precipitation from weatherundergroud. I'm able to parse the necessary json data however when I attempt to add a time stamp to the DB entry I'm unable to populate the DB. I'm able to use this syntax with one variable however and relevant DB change however not with 2 variables in addition to the time stamp. Here is a simplified version of the code:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('precip.sqlite3')
curs = conn.cursor()

curs.execute('''
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Precip
(timestamp DATETIME, date TEXT, precip TEXT)''')

date = js["history"]["date"]["pretty"]
precip = js["history"]["dailysummary"][0]["precipm"]

print "date:", date, "precipitation", precip, "mm"

curs.execute("INSERT INTO Precip values(datetime('now'),(?, ?))",(date, precip,))
conn.commit()
```

which fails with this error:
curs.execute("INSERT INTO Precip values(datetime('now'),(?, ?))",(date, precip,))
sqlite3.OperationalError: near ",": syntax error

Comment: `INSERT INTO Precip values(datetime('now'),?, ?)"` makes more sense to me.

Comment: thanks! that resolved it although I'm not sure why the extra bracket grouping causes the error.

Comment: I'd assume the parentheses group the two entries inside them into a single entry, hence you're inserting only two entries into the table, the second one being a composite one.

Answer (score 1):

There are too many parentheses in the SQL statement:

```sql
INSERT INTO Precip values(datetime('now'),(?, ?))
```

`(?,?)` would be a row value with two columns, which does not make sense here.

The VALUES clause expectes three expressions, so just give it exactly that:

```sql
INSERT INTO Precip VALUES (datetime('now'), ?, ?)
```